# Web scraping giving different responses

Tags: html, http, dart, web-scraping

I have this dart code, but it gives different outputs everytime i run it

Steps to reproduce
Add both files to same directory
Run

dart pub get

dart code.dart

It will create ten files having different contents

Create a file named code.dart

```
import "dart:io";
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:html/parser.dart';


Future<String> scrapLyrics(String lyricsUrl) async {
  final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(lyricsUrl));
  var document = parse(response.body);

  return document.getElementsByClassName('lyrics')[0].text;
}

main() async {
    String ly;
  
  for (int i = 1; i <=10; i++) {
    print("Request number $i");
  try{
     ly= await scrapLyrics("https://www.genius.com/The-chainsmokers-closer-lyrics");
  }
  catch(e){
    ly=e.toString();
  }
    File file = File("file$i.txt");
    await file.writeAsString("$ly");
  
    ly="";
  }
}
```

Create a file pubspec.yaml

```
name: my_app
environment:
  sdk: '>=2.10.0 <3.0.0'
dependencies:
  http: ^0.13.3
  html: ^0.15.0
```

Obtained Output(in some cases):
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0

Answer (score 0):

The class name you're looking for is `"Lyrics__Container-sc-1ynbvzw-8"` not `"lyrics"`

Comment: @Edie_Kamau Actually it is different in mobile

Comment: ``` return document.getElementsByClassName('lyrics')[0].text; ``` is returning an empty list, thus  throwing ``` RangeError ``` while accessing the 1st element. If you are positive the class name is ``` "lyrics" ``` I'm not sure why Range error is being thrown.

Comment: @Edie_Kamau the site gives different html code on different runs

Comment: @Edie_Kamau if possible can i contact u on a different platform?

Comment: @SHUVAMJASWAL Telegram maybe

Comment: @Edie_Kamau can u text me
https://t.me/ShuvamTheBeast